# How do I hide a site from search engines?

Tags: search, hide

I am looking to hide a site so that it doesn't show up in any search engine just wondering how I would go about this?

Comment: Is this supposed to be "security through obscurity" or are you doing something malicious?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a robots.txt file: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=156449

Comment: Also password protect the entire site.

Comment: According to that link, "You should not use robots.txt as a means to hide your web pages from Google Search results. This is because other pages might point to your page, and your page could get indexed that way, avoiding the robots.txt file.  If you want to block your page from search results, use another method such as password protection or noindex tags or directives."  See https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag

Answer (score 3):

Apart from password-protecting your site, you could add these lines to `robots.txt`:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

This doesn't **hide** the site but rather instructs bots not to spider the content.

Answer (score 2):

You can *somehow* reduce your site being listed using a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html). Note that this depends on the "goodwill" of the crawler, though (some spambots will explicitly look at locations that you disallow).

The only safe and reliable way of not having a site listed, sadly, is not putting it on the internet.

Simply not linking to your site will not work. Crawlers get their info from many sources, including browser referrers and domain registrars. So, in order to be "invisible", you would have to not visit your site and not register a domain (only access it via IP address).
And then, if you run your webserver based on IP address, you still have all the spambots probing random addresses. It will take a while, but they will find you.

Password protecting your site should work, effectively making it inaccessible. Though (and it is beyond my comprehension how that happens) for example there are literally thousands of ACM papers listed in Google which you cannot see without an account and logging in. Yet they are there.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/), deny from all search engines.
They don't all respect robots.txt so check your server logs regularly and deny from ranges of suspected robots/crawlers:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html

Answer (score 0):

You use a `robots.txt` file. Place the file in the root of the site with this content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 0):

most proper search engines uses bots or crawlers to websites and index them. you could [Robot File method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at `nofollow` [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow)

Answer (score -1):

You need to read about robots.txt file you are supposed to copy in your site's webroot – http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html.