# Private (invisible) html page

Tags: html, upload, visibility

How would I upload an html file to my website and not have it be visible to the world? I don't want it showing up on Google or Bing or any weird web spider matrix bot thing being able to see it. I don't want it password protected. I just want it invisible and to be the only person who knows the url.

It would be something like.

My-Website.com/INVISIBLE.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732653/how-do-i-hide-a-site-from-search-engines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding robots.txt to your page should do it

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449

Answer (score 4):

Your webpage `My-Website.com/INVISIBLE.html` stays unknown to the world unless you tell someone about it. To make it restricted to search engines, you could use a `robots.txt` file, details of which are documented at http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html however not all search engines respect the robots.txt file.